# Manipulating userforms using xlwings

Tags: python, excel, xlwings, vba

I was trying to find out the methods of the pywin32 object of a userform ComboBox in Excel, but I honestly has no idea what I'm doing and got nowhere.

VBA Code (Sending combobox object to python):

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    s = test(ComboBox1)
End Sub
```

Python Code :

```
@xw.func
def test(obj):
    print(obj._dict__)
```

So, the print above returned this :

```
{'_oleobj_': <PyIDispatch at 0x03957A90 with obj at 0x01218C8C>, '_username_': 'IMdcCombo', '_olerepr_': <win32com.client.build.LazyDispatchItem object at 0x03FB0FD0>, '_mapCachedItems_': {}, '_builtMethods_': {}, '_enum_': None, '_unicode_to_string_': None, '_lazydata_': (<PyITypeInfo at 0x03957B50 with obj at 0x0121919C>, <PyITypeComp at 0x03957B68 with obj at 0x012196F4>)}
```

I guess I was expecting to see the same methods/properties found in VBA, but I have no idea what to take from this.

Anyone knows a way to manipulate userform/controls directly from python using xlwings?

Specifically I'm looking for dynamically adding new controls to the userform, reading/modifying controls attributes, and ideally modifying their events, all through python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I guess I was expecting to see the same methods/properties found in VBA, but I have no idea what to take from this.

You can take anything from *this*, but *this* isn't a real `Combobox` nor something from `COM` environment - it's just a "wrapper" object over a `COM` object, implemented via [`IDispatch`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDispatch) interface, and it's possibily thanks to the `win32com` dependency.

Because of that there's no an "intellisense"-like feature, but you're still able to use properties/methods:

```
@xw.func
def test(obj):
    #   accesing method
    obj.AddItem('Hello world!')
    #   accesing property
    obj.Enabled = False
```

also you can pass an `UserForm` as `obj` to [add](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/free-training/ExcelVBA2/excelvba2lesson21.htm) a new control to it:

```
@xw.func
def test(obj):
    #   add new label
    control = obj.Add('Forms.Label.1')
    #   accesing property
    control.Caption = 'Hello world!'
```

Comment: Wow that seems kinda magical... So I can just call the methods by the same name? Even though they won't show in the __dict__ property...

Comment: @Mojimi, No, it's not a magic. All Excel stuff comes from foreign (relative to Python, of course) environment, hence there's no straight solution to list all of properties/methods. Bright side - you can just use them like in plain VBA.

Comment: So, as UGP said, there's no way to add the events directly to the object through python , right? Even if they were added as VBA code in string

Comment: @Mojimi, you can write vba routines/functions/events into code modules at runtime. And if it's possible from Excel (it is) then it's possible from Python in a same fashion.

Comment: Well in Excel you include events to already existing controls through the GUI, I wouldn't know how to add them programatically, specially through Python.

Answer (score 1):

When looking under the [documentation](http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#xlwings.main.Shapes) for xlWings under the `Shape`there does seem to be access to all properties.

Under [missing features](http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/missing_features.html), you can find a workaround using `.api` to access all vba methods. Through this you could create and modify controls, just like you would do in VBA.

Also what you could do is using the [`macro(name)`](http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#app)-function you could create functions in VBA to modify, create `comboboxes` and pass values to the function, i.e to create a `combobox` at position x, y , width, height and pass these parameters trough python.

As it seems, you cannot access events trough `xlWings`. But i've found [IronPython](http://www.ironpython.info/index.php?title=Interacting_with_Excel), it uses the .NET interop facilities to access the excel object and events. As you can see under the [documentation](http://ironpython.net/documentation/dotnet/), you can work with the excel object as you would do in `C#, VB.NET`etc..

So as a conclusion, i would suggest you looking up the documentations of both. As they both reveal the excel object to python you should be able to do what you want with one of them.

Comment: Your answer gave great insight, but I'm accepting the other as it made the homework for me